# запрет повторного запуска скрипта

Tags: windows, node.js

Как в nodejs реализовать запрет повторного запуска скрипта, если скрипт выполняется в данный момент?

Можно использовать файловый мьютекс

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lockfile

```
var lockFile = require('lockfile')

try{
    lockFile.lockSync('some-file.lock');
}catch(er){ 
    if(er!=undefined){ 
        process.exit();
    }
}

//single run code below
```

Но тут есть проблема, если процесс ноды будет закрыт через диспетчер задач, то лок файл не удалится => скрипт больше никогда отработать не сможет.

Есть ли другие варианты помимо написания своего модуля?

Comment: самое простое - отруби скрипт и добавь счетчик.

Comment: @dasauser что я должен отрубить и какой счетчик добавить?

Comment: можешь сделать обработчик удаляющий файл на [beforeExit](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit)

Comment: @nörbörnën The 'beforeExit' event is not emitted for conditions causing explicit termination, such as calling process.exit() or uncaught exceptions.

Comment: ну тогда обработчик на [SIGHUP](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events)

Comment: @Kopkan, что отрубить? скрипт, который работает в данный момент. какой счетчик? счетчик отработки скрипта. var var = 1, перед запуском добавляешь проверку и после того как скрипт отработает меняешь его на 1.

Comment: @dasauser счетчик же у нас конечно имеет лок на уровне системы) ну никакой гонки данных не будет же)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью модуля ffi можно вызывать функции из dll

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ffi

Но данный модуль перекрывает коды `GetLastError`, поэтому пришлось использовать `WaitForSingleObject` для подтверждения захвата мьютекса

```
function tryGetMutex(mutexName, isGlobal=true){

    if (isGlobal) {
        mutexName = "Global\\" + mutexName;
    }

    var ffi = require('ffi');
    var kernel = ffi.Library('Kernel32.dll', {
        'CreateMutexA': [ 'int', ['int', 'int', 'string'] ],
        'WaitForSingleObject': [ 'int', ['int','int'] ]
    });

    var mutex = kernel.CreateMutexA(0, 0, "Global\\" + mutexName);
    var wait = kernel.WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 1000);

    return( wait==0 || wait==128 );//WAIT_ABANDONED || WAIT_OBJECT_0
}

if(tryGetMutex("mymutex"))
{
    console.log("I single run code");
    setInterval(function(){}, 1000);
}
else{
    console.log("mutex lock in another application");
    process.exit();
}
```